# Why sending a message to a web socket does not yield control to the event loop?

Tags: websocket, python-asyncio, event-loop, python-internals

Consider the following code:

main.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)
        print(message)


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

other.py

```
import asyncio
import json

import websockets

tasks = set()


async def run_job(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.)
    print(f"I'm job number {i}")


async def bunch_of_tasks(ws):
    for i in range(10):
        task = asyncio.create_task(run_job(i), name=f'job-{i}')
        tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(tasks.discard)
        print(f'had a nice sleep! now my value is {i}')
        # await asyncio.sleep(0.)
        await ws.send(json.dumps('hello there!'))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(f'tasks done')


async def do_stuff():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
        await bunch_of_tasks(websocket)
        await websocket.recv()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(do_stuff())
```

By first running `main.py` and then running in parallel `other.py`, I get:

```
had a nice sleep! now my value is 0
had a nice sleep! now my value is 1
had a nice sleep! now my value is 2
had a nice sleep! now my value is 3
had a nice sleep! now my value is 4
had a nice sleep! now my value is 5
had a nice sleep! now my value is 6
had a nice sleep! now my value is 7
had a nice sleep! now my value is 8
had a nice sleep! now my value is 9
I'm job number 0
I'm job number 1
I'm job number 2
I'm job number 3
I'm job number 4
I'm job number 5
I'm job number 6
I'm job number 7
I'm job number 8
I'm job number 9
tasks done
```

But if I uncomment `await asyncio.sleep(0.)` before `await ws.send(json.dumps('hello there!'))`, I get:

```
had a nice sleep! now my value is 0
had a nice sleep! now my value is 1
I'm job number 0
had a nice sleep! now my value is 2
I'm job number 1
had a nice sleep! now my value is 3
I'm job number 2
had a nice sleep! now my value is 4
I'm job number 3
had a nice sleep! now my value is 5
I'm job number 4
had a nice sleep! now my value is 6
I'm job number 5
had a nice sleep! now my value is 7
I'm job number 6
had a nice sleep! now my value is 8
I'm job number 7
had a nice sleep! now my value is 9
I'm job number 8
I'm job number 9
tasks done
```

which is somehow what I would expect.

So apparently sending the message to the web socket does not yield control to the event loop, and the `run_job` coroutine does not have the opportunity to be run. However, `asyncio.sleep` effectively suspends the current task and gives an opportunity to `run_job` to be executed.

Why that happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: indeed - `await` is not in itself sufficient to warrant control is passed back to the cooperative part of the asyncio loop. To ensure that, a low-level callback has to be scheduled somewhere down the call chain (and `asyncio.sleep` does that).

Long answer:

I had to debug that out -
It happens that although everything is in place for `websockets` clients being async, it boils down to write all data it is sending in the Selector socket at once - since it is non-constrained otherwise.

In other words,  `ws.send` will eventually call this line synchronously: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f2e5a6ee628502d307a97f587788d7022a200229/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L1071

And then, the big surprise is that for  raw-coroutines (co-routines not wrapped in tasks or futures), whenever they return their value, the execution does not yield to the asyncio-loop - and even if they contain other "await" statements, if the nested awaited co-routines do not actually would "block" in an await, the asyncio loop is never reached back.
Internally, in the C code handling co-routines, whenever a co-routine actually "blocks" after a send, a callback is scheduled: this callback is wrapped in a Python `asyncio.events.Handle` object, and the control is then returned to the asyncio loop.

The code for that is in this C function: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f2e5a6ee628502d307a97f587788d7022a200229/Modules/_asynciomodule.c#L2696 . If you follow along there, you can see that if the co-routine returned a value, its result is set in the low-level object. If it returned from `send` with another awaitable, that one is scheduled in the loop, and the function returns.

It may be (and probably is) an implementation choice of asyncio Loops: any  so called co-routine that actually resolves synchronously is run synchronously, for performance reasons.

Only when any of the nested co-routines called in an await ends up scheduling a future with a callback, in the leaf call, (which `asyncio.sleep` does), do the asyncio default loop runs through all other ready tasks. (another full execution of its `._run_once` method in `asyncio.base_events.BaseEventLoop`).

Comment: That is a great answer! Thank you so much @jsbueno for the deep research and awesome explanation!

Comment: oh... I was fooled by the inner implementation of asyncio. `ws.send` eventually makes a synchronous call... Indeed we can observe the same result for any call to a synchronous function converted to a coroutine. So if I replace `await ws.send(json.dumps('hello there!'))` by `await sleep()` and the definition of `sleep` is just `async def sleep(): time.sleep(0.1)` the `run_job(i`) tasks will be executed at the end. Thanks a lot for this deep explanation.