# arrange disrupted output in cmd when Read streaming output from async subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

This code runs in **Pycharm** without any problems but when I want to run in **Command Prompt** outputs arrange disrupted

I have two files called **test.py** and **test1.py** whose codes are as follows.
**test1.py** is executed by **test.py** and its output is displayed at **test.py** console.

**test1.py**

```
import logging
import time

logging.error(1)
time.sleep(1)
print(2)
time.sleep(1)
print(3)
time.sleep(1)
logging.error(4)
time.sleep(1)
logging.error(5)
time.sleep(1)
print(6)
```

**test.py**

```
import asyncio


async def _read_stream(stream, cb):
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if line:
            cb(line)
        else:
            break


async def _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd,
                                                   stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_task = asyncio.create_task(_read_stream(process.stdout, stdout_cb))
    stderr_task = asyncio.create_task(_read_stream(process.stderr, stderr_cb))

    await asyncio.wait([stdout_task, stderr_task])
    return await process.wait()


def execute(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb):
    asyncio.run(_stream_subprocess(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(execute(["pipenv", "run", "python", 'test1.py'],
                  lambda x: print("STDOUT: %s" % x),
                  lambda x: print("STDERR: %s" % x),))
```

When I run the **test.py** in **PyCharm**, the program runs without problems and its output is as follows:

```
STDERR: b'ERROR:root:1\r\n'
STDOUT: b'2\r\n'
STDOUT: b'3\r\n'
STDERR: b'ERROR:root:4\r\n'
STDERR: b'ERROR:root:5\r\n'
STDOUT: b'6\r\n'
```

But when I run the **test.py** in **Command Prompt**, the output arrangement is disturbed and **STDOUT** is not properly executed. its output is as follows:

```
STDERR: b'ERROR:root:1\r\n'
STDERR: b'ERROR:root:4\r\n'
STDERR: b'ERROR:root:5\r\n'
STDOUT: b'2\r\n'
STDOUT: b'3\r\n'
STDOUT: b'6\r\n'
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that in some your environments reading from the stdin already has the data available, so `line = await stream.readline()` won't really make the asyncio loop through other tasks: if the data is there, it simply will return synchronously.

So your tasks for stdin and stderr will run one after the other.

I don't think fixing this will ensure you a determistic order, though  - you really should just pipe your stdin and stderr messages to a common queue instead of relying on asyncio tasks to yield the messages in the order they show up.

Anyway, adding an extra `asyncio.sleep` call in your `_read_stream()`  function should give you the same behavior in both environments:

```
async def _read_stream(stream, cb):
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Ensures the asyncio loop steps through all ready tasks
        if line:
            cb(line)
        else:
            break
```

Yes - I also thought  any `await` would always give a chance to other tasks to run - last week, when answering a similar question here I found out it not to be so - check my lengthier answer at:
[Why sending a message to a web socket does not yield control to the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834800/why-sending-a-message-to-a-web-socket-does-not-yield-control-to-the-event-loop/75837663#75837663)