# asyncio+pymongo two cursors parallel iterate not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, python-asyncio

My goal is to query data from two mongodb databases, src and dst, but the time-consuming of the following two writing methods is the same. Is there anything wrong with me?

1.The src and dst query times for this method are similar

```py
    async def get_src_cursor_data(self, src_coll, values, start_idx):
        start4 = time.time()
        
        src_cursor = src_coll.find({"_id": {"$in": values}})
        if not isinstance(src_cursor, list):
            while src_cursor.alive:
                doc = await src_cursor.next()
                
        end4 = time.time()
        self.log_info('[{}] get_src_cursor_data: {}'.format(start_idx, end4 - start4))

    async def get_dst_cursor_data(self, dst_coll, values, start_idx):
        start5 = time.time()

        dst_cursor = dst_coll.find({"_id": {"$in": values}})
        if not isinstance(dst_cursor, list):
            while dst_cursor.alive:
                dst = await dst_cursor.next()
               
        end5 = time.time()
        self.log_info('[{}] get_dst_cursor_data: {}'.format(start_idx, end5 - start5))

    async def process_document(self, src_coll, dst_coll, values, start_idx):
        start = time.time()
        res = await asyncio.gather(self.get_src_cursor_data(src_coll, values, start_idx),
                                   self.get_dst_cursor_data(dst_coll, values, start_idx))

        end0 = time.time()
        self.log_info(
            "[{}] process {} docs total time :{}".format(
                start_idx, len(values), end0 - start0))
```

```
[20] get_src_cursor_data: 5.120812177658081 
[60] get_src_cursor_data: 5.62122654914856 
[0] get_src_cursor_data: 6.334164142608643 
[80] get_src_cursor_data: 6.916379451751709 
[40] get_src_cursor_data: 7.283424139022827 
[20] get_dst_cursor_data: 5.805237531661987 
[20] process 20 docs total time :10.929065227508545, get src data time :5.120812177658081, get dst data time: 5.805237531661987
```

2.The src and dst query time of this method is twice that of method 1

```py
    async def process_sample_document(self, src_coll, dst_coll, values, start_idx):
        start4 = time.time()
        src_cursor = src_coll.find({"_id": {"$in": values}})
        if not isinstance(src_cursor, list):
            while src_cursor.alive:
                doc = await src_cursor.next()
        end4 = time.time()
        self.log_info('[{}] get_src_cursor_data: {}'.format(start_idx, end4 - start4))

        start5 = time.time()
        dst_cursor = dst_coll.find({"_id": {"$in": values}})
        if not isinstance(dst_cursor, list):
            while dst_cursor.alive:
                dst = await dst_cursor.next()
        end5 = time.time()
        self.log_info('[{}] get_dst_cursor_data: {}'.format(start_idx, end5 - start5))
        
        self.log_info(
            "[{}] process {} docs total time :{}, get src data time :{}, get dst data time: {}".format(start_idx, len(values), end5 - start4, end4 - start4, end5 - start5))
```

```
[0] get_dst_cursor_data: 9.8009352684021 
[40] get_dst_cursor_data: 10.02169156074524 
[20] get_dst_cursor_data: 10.243099212646484 
[60] get_dst_cursor_data: 10.4615159034729 
[80] get_dst_cursor_data: 10.679930925369263 
[0] get_src_cursor_data: 10.909341096878052 
[40] get_src_cursor_data: 11.130756378173828 
[80] get_src_cursor_data: 11.351166486740112 
[20] get_src_cursor_data: 11.579554557800293 
[60] get_src_cursor_data: 11.807490825653076 
[0] process 20 docs total time :11.81546807289123
```

In the end, the total time consumption of the two methods is the same.I don't understand why

I want to be able to query data in parallel to reduce time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, although presenting an async method that can be awaited, the call to `cursor.next()` does not, under the hood, pass any control back to the asyncio loop - being a somewhat "fake" async method.

That can happen even if does have prevision to do that, but happen, at each call, to have data ready for consumption - as I found out when answering this other question: [Why sending a message to a web socket does not yield control to the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834800/why-sending-a-message-to-a-web-socket-does-not-yield-control-to-the-event-loop/75837663#75837663)

The way to ensure the asyncio loop is able to switch tasks and run both concurrently is to add an extra `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in your inner loops, just after you fetch each cursor row.

This might not take the total time down if the underlying lib is actually making blocking calls in its `next` method, but at least the tasks processing will be interleaved.

```
            ...
            while src_cursor.alive:
                doc = await src_cursor.next()
                await asyncio.sleep(0)  # ensures other tasks can run
            ...
```

Comment: I see! Thanks for your answer.! What I also want to know is why the time of the second method keeps increasing